# Row not moving when changing the model with NSFetchResultsController

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm working on my first iPhone app here (a basic to-do list app) and just added NSFetchResultsController into my table view. I have 2 sections of rows and I have no problem adding rows, and they're sorted by whether the goal's completed attribute is true - if it is, then it goes to the bottom section and it's crossed out.

And whenever you swipe right on a row in the top section, it changes the goal's complete attribute to true and moves it to the bottom section:

```
  RegimenGoal *goal = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:swipedIndexPath];
  goal.completed = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

  [context save:&error];
```

Here's my [view controller code](https://github.com/sayem/regimen/blob/master/Regimen/RegimenDayController.m).

For some reason, this is only working on goals that I just created, but doesn't work on existing goals that I've added. After some debugging, I realized that NSFetchedResultsChangeMove is not being fired off, instead NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate is whenever I'm doing this action on existing goals that aren't new.

Came across this on the Apple docs too, ["Moved Objects Sometimes Reported as Updated"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/iPhone/NSFetchedResultsChangeMoveReportedAsNSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate/_index.html). And I tried the work-around listed there by simply checking whether the completed attribute is true or not.

And when I do that, I see that the newIndexPath isn't new - it's simply the old indexPath, and that's stumping me... any idea on why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in the creation of the fetched results controller. If you group the results into sections by specifying `sectionNameKeyPath:@"completed"`, then you must add a first sort descriptor using the same key:

```
NSSortDescriptor *completeSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"completed" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *daySort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"dateCreated" ascending:YES];
[dayRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:completeSort, daySort, nil]];
```

Another problem is in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell formatCell:indexPath.section];
```

Here you assume that section 0 contains all items with `completed = NO` and section 1 contains all items with `completed = YES`. But if all items are completed, then there is only one section (section 0), containing all the completed items. So you can not use `indexPath.section` as argument to `formatCell`. You should use the value of `goal.completed` instead. For example, you could move the `formatCell` call into the `configureCell:atIndexPath:` method:

```
- (void)configureCell:(RegimenCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    RegimenGoal *goal = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.label.text = goal.text;
    [cell formatCell:goal.completed.intValue];
}
```

And now it does not make much sense to make the table cell `reuseIdentifier` dependent on the section and row number. I think you can just replace

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-%d", indexPath.row, indexPath.section];
```

by a fixed string

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = @"YourCellIdentifer";
```

A similar problem is in the `setNavTitle` method:

```
int goalsCount = [_tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0];
int completedCount = [_tableView numberOfRowsInSection:1];
```

Again, if all goals are completed, they are all in section 0, and there is no section 1. Your current code would display "(0%)" in that case instead of "(100%)".

*Further Remarks:*

- The "Moved Objects Sometimes Reported as Updated" workaround seems not to be necessary here.
- For an `NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate` event, you can call either `[self configureCell:...]` or `[[_tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:...]`. Calling both is not necessary.
- The instance variable `_fetchedResultsController` should be used only in the `fetchedResultsController` method, which creates the fetched results controller (FRC) on demand. At all other places, you should use `self.fetchedResultsController` to ensure that the FRC is created if necessary.

Comment: Thanks so much, Martin! I appreciate it. I didn't know that I had to include complete in the sort descriptor too, and you're right about the cell formatting and navtitle. For my reuseIdentifier, I still need to flag it by row/section somehow for strike-out label I'm subviewing, so I did it by goal.completed instead.